# Hibernate one to many relationship for saving data to multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, entity-relationship

I have the following two tables with hibernate : one-to-many relationship.

1) Notifications

`<class name="Notification" table="notifications" >
<id name="id" column="id"><generator class="native"/></id>`

`<set name="Preference" table="preference" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
<key>
    <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
</key>`

`<one-to-many class="Preference" />
</set>
</class>`

---

> (NOTE : Inside the Notification class i have a member like
>   `Set<Preference> Preference`)

---

2) Preference

`<class name="Preference" table="preference">
<id name="id" column="id">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>`

`<property name="userId" column="user_id" />`

`<property name="sectorId" column="sector_id" />`

`<property name="stateId" column="state_id" />
</class>`

Hiberante **query** that i have used.

Notification notification = ......;
(Objects are inserted to this **Notification** object)

> getHibernateTemplate().merge(notification);

So, the problem is objects for Preference not saved. but the data for Notification has saved correctly.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you post the java code where you create objects and make queries?

Comment: **@Teg** -- I have found answer on my own and I have posted below. Anyhow thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on myself. The answer is change the attribute in the (one-to-many) hibernate configuration **inverse="true"** to be **false**. If I set inverse as **true** I have to configure, another many-to-one configuration in the other class.

Changes to be done if the **invese="true"** for the question that i have asked above.

2) Preference

```
<class name="Preference" table="preference"> <id name="id" column="id"> 
<generator class="native"/> </id>
......
<many-to-one name="notification" class="Notification" fetch="select">
   <column name="id" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
</class>
```

Thanks guys!!